# Error installing OS with Noobs

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, noobs

I have a Raspberry PI model 2B and tried to install Raspbian and OpenELEC through it. I followed the correct installation procedures and the installation succeeded the first time but OpenELEC was not booting, Raspbian was working fine. Then I went into recovery mode on Noobs and went to reinstall both of them I get an error: Data_Partition:Error mounting file system. This error is shown at the end of the installation procedure. If I restart the Pi it goes back to Noobs OS installation selection. I also tried installing just Raspbian but that didn't work either. Same problem if I try it with Noobs Lite. And I get the ACT LED flashing 7 times after this ( 7 flashes: kernel.img not found).

Edit: I tried flashing the card with Raspbian and it worked fine, no problems resisted. I tested Raspbian for a couple of days and didn't see any errors with the card nor the filesystem. Then I formatted the card and tried Noobs again, the card got corrupt.

My conclusion: It seems Noobs doesnt like my micro-SD for some reason or Noobs is having an issue with the formatting my card.

Comment: Are you powering anything else off of the Pi's USB ports?

Comment: 2 X USB mouse and keyboard

Comment: Stupid question. This is probably a power supply issue, but... Have you tried a different card?

Comment: Yea, same issue with a lower speed card. I'm using a 1A 5V supply.

Comment: Well, if NOOBs is not working, have you tried to manually flash your card with OpenELEC?

Comment: You mentioned a 1A power supply.  While I personally don't know if 1A is acceptable, I have not had issues with a 2A supply.

Comment: Plzzz follow this tutorial; it discusses the simple steps to install the OS in Raspberry pi link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQkWezL_6bA

Answer (score 4):

From what you have stated I would look for a power issue. If you have a poor power supply it can cause your SD card to get corrupted. Look for the rainbow icon in the upper right. You can re-image your card (it is not ruined), but it can keep happening.

Comment: I have an Apple USB voltage source 5V 1A supply and it's a genuine. Is this too low for the pi?

Comment: I just tried with a 1.9A 5V power supply, same problem.

Comment: Same problem as in the card got corrupted again? Or as in the new power supply didn't fix the existing corrupted card?

Comment: Both, I reformatted the card and retried Noobs again, it kept getting corrupt.

Comment: Given what you have said, I still lean towards a power issue. What other USB peripherals do you have connected? And do you have a monitor attached during the install process? And do you see the rainbow icon in the upper corner.

Answer (score -4):

Answer:

there is no problem in your power system ! 
second there is a virus attack your SD card reader or your flash when you copy the OS file on it so i faced the same problem but i am not tested yet. but i think this is what is happen

so you need to install the SDM antivirus its for free you do not need a product key and do  a scan for your SD card reader or whatever you use before copying the OS on it

you will see some file on your sd card  that does mean any senses, all what you should to do is to deleted and check again if you put the sd card not giving any recovery file or hidden file again

i hope if that make a solution for your probs

Comment: So despite testing it you have determined that it is a virus despite reformatting of the SD card. What are you basing this on?

Comment: i was  the same prob format do not take away virus, virus will detect you when you get acces on the sd card like copying some some thing on it btw i will test that tomorrow and if that work i will confirm that and SDAM its for usb antivirus

Comment: Then why did straight Raspbian work normally?